# Write the list of all the normal series of $\mathbb{Z}_{105}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In this problem they ask to do a list of all the normal series of $\mathbb{Z}_{105}$ and their respective factor group. I also have to point out which series are from a composition.

Is there any hint so I can solve it myself?

My Path:

We observe that $\mathbb{Z}_{105} = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ and do the Hasse diagram

then the normal series are:

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{15}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{3}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{15}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{5}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{21}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{3}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{21}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{7}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{35}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{5}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{35}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{7}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{15}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{21}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{35}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{3}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{5}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{7}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

and the only normal Series from a composition is the trivial

$\{e\}=⟨\overline{105}⟩ \subseteq ⟨\overline{1}⟩ = \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

Comment: Every subgroup is normal, so I'd start by listing all subgroups and writing them in a lattice.

Comment: Also, every normal subgroup is again cyclic, so all their normal subgroups are in turn just as easy to find as those of $\mathbb Z_{105}$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**:

if $G_1$, ... , $G_n$ are pairwise non-isomorphic simple groups, then all normal subgroups of $\prod_{i=1}^n G_i$ are of the form $\prod_{i \in S} G_i$ for some $S \subset \{1, ... , n\}$ (one for each such $S$)

**Hint 2**:

> $\mathbb{Z}_{105} = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$

Comment: One minor comment: $\prod$ ("\prod", for product) is more appropriate here than $\bigotimes$.